# Authentication prevents posting to Classic ASP from Web form using WebClient() from Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, post, asp-classic, windows-authentication

I am managing and old web site (site, not application) that is a hybrid of Web Forms and Classic ASP.  The Classic ASP is being phased out, but that is probably a year away.  Right now, we are dropping the old form of authentication in favor of Windows Authentication in the web.config.

The problem is that I am attempting to post to a Classic page from the code behind of a web form (`http://www.blahsiblah.com/index.aspx`) and am getting a 401 error.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var urlClassicASP = "http://www.blahsiblah.com/classic.asp";
var responseArray = webClient.UploadValues(urlClassicASP, "POST", nameValueCollection);
```

This throws "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"

My question is, how can I post to the classic page without invoking the authentication of the dotNet side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to set:

```
webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this
Here is a simple suggestion that I hope helps

.Net
Use 127.0.0.1 (or your internal 192.169 / 10.1* ) IP to post to the page vs the public URL
Add a parameter (call it 'bypassauth' or something unique ) when sending the request to the ASP page
Add a parameter that identifies the user that you have authenticated in the .Net side

ASP
Find the include where the authentication check is happening and in that check, add another condition before returning 401 that checks two things
1) Request is from local/internal IP
2) Has the bypassauth parameter 
3) the user id is valid

This way your old ASP code will still continue to work if requested from a browser and expect user to be authenticated however, when sending the request from .net will let you bypass authentication

I'm sure there are other ideas too, but this is just one approach